# SharePoint 2013 TimeSheet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

I want to create time sheet for my team on SharePoint 2013. I think Project Site Template is best to create time sheet but I'm not sure how to start, specially how to create multiple task so when user will add hours for that particular task it will show the total daily working hours,weekly working hours and monthly working hours.

Not sure below format which I'm going to create is correct? Can any one please advice me and provide some steps so I can try this. Thanks for your help in advance,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Create custom list with columns Date, Employee ID, Employee Name, Task Name, Comments, Hours spent
2. Customize New Item form for that list to perhaps autofill Employee details when form is opened so it's quicker to fill in hours without having to always select own details. Or perhaps make Employee fields disabled on the form (or even hidden) so people cannot fill in hours for other people.
3. Create custom web part, or page with custom JavaScript (e.g., jQuery) that reads the custom list (via server side, if it is custom web part, or via CSOM if it's JavaScript) and sums up the daily/weekly/monthly hours and presents them in a nice table.

As it looks like to be Office 365, I'd probably go with the JavaScript and CSOM route, while Sandboxed Web Parts should work and do the trick as well but people are beginning to be afraid of using them as they might go away some time in there far future.

There are several nice table libraries for jQuery, so creating the table should be a breeze.